# How to hide VPN password?

Tags: password, vpn

I use Ubuntu 20.04. I have a VPN L2TP connection. When I go to VPN settings I can click on the "show password" checkbox and see the password, also I can see the Pre-shared key phrase. This password should be saved on the PC, and the user shouldn't know this password at all.

In this case, I wonder, how to hide this password or restrict users to see it.